# SQLCE Insert sql error "The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = somefieldname ]"

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am facing an error while executing a simple insert command with SQLCE Database.

SQL:

```
insert into accountgroups (AcGroupId, AcGroupParentID, AcGroupName, AcGroupAlias, AcNatureID, AcBaseNatureID) values ('1', '0', 'Current Assets', '', '4', '1')
```

ERROR:

```
{"The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = AcGroupId ]"}
```

I tried to execute the same command in VS2010 Studio SQL editor. And getting this error

```
 Error Code: 80004005
 Message   : The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = AcGroupId ]
 Minor Err.: 25004
 Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
 Err. Par. : AcGroupId
```

The above command is working fine with MySQL Database.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the AcGroupId not simply set to auto increment, and therefore cannot be set manually?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's was an auto increment field. As for solution I have removed auto increment on it and working fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! Since my guess turned out to be correct, I guess I might as well add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert into the ID column thusly:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT accountgroups ON
insert into accountgroups (AcGroupId, AcGroupParentID, AcGroupName, AcGroupAlias, AcNatureID, AcBaseNatureID) values ('1', '0', 'Current Assets', '', '4', '1')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT accountgroups OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

`AcGroupId` appears to be an ID column, and those are often set to auto-increment and can therefore not be set manually. If you remove the first column and the first value of your query, it will probably work.